# Jmeter API automation in Host and inside Host

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I have scenario like I need to run one API curl request which is in **12.34.567** after logging into this I have to login one more host **98.76.543**.

After logged in to second host I have to run *curl -XPOST -H"Content-type:json" http://localhost:8080/test/ --/file
Json*

Am able to connect using ssh sampler to first host but inside that I have to log one more host. Can anyone please help out from this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On which machine you have installed the JMeter ?

Comment: Hye Sariq I have installed jmeter in my local mac machine

Comment: The rule is simple, from your machine site should be accessible through http otherwise it won’t be possible to record/automate it. I am not sure about any other approach for the same.

Comment: Hye Sariq, We can access those Host through ssh only.

Comment: Let's  pretend mumbers you give are valid IPs. What are you doing? `ssh 12.34.567` from here `ssh 98.76.543` and finally `curl -XPOST -H"Content-type:json" http://localhost:8080/test/ --/file Json`? And you want use jMeter to do perf test? Is it right?

Comment: Yeah lojza, that's right

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the host via [SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol) only you can consider using [JMeter SSH Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) in order to execute arbitrary SSH command, including [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), something like:

[image]

If everything goes well you should be able to see the response in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, apply [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.

[image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)

**SSH Command** sampler can be installed as a part of `SSH Protocol Support` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Hey @Dmitri, am able to execute above one, but I have one more host inside first host. I need to execute command in second host.

Comment: Thanks all got solutions. Connected using beanshll java script